# How can I Download Files from Laravel Forge (Wordpress) to Local Machine?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-forge

I have installed WordPress on a site through Laravel Forge and would like to download it to start working to improve it at my local machine. How can I download it?

I've tried:
scp forge@myip:/mysite.com /Users/myname/sites

I am getting either this error if I do `scp` from local:
`ssh: connect to host 111.111.111.111(fake_ip_on_forge) port 22: Operation timed out`

or this error if I do `scp` from the remote server on Laravel Forge.
`scp: /mysite.com: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the most likely scenario is that you can't ssh into the machine. First, you need to verify that you can `ssh forge@forgeip` then your `scp` command should work just fine, assuming that /mysite.com is the correct directory. You'll also need to copy it recursively, so a `scp -r` will probably be in order.

Here's some documentation on [setting up ssh access in forge](https://blog.laravel.com/forge-connect-to-your-server-using-ssh-or-sftp)

You can also learn more about scp flags in the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have had no prob on ssh forgr@forgeip though. Also tried `-r` without luck.